# Open iOS app from mail link

Tags: ios

When user press on a link of mail then how to open installed app in iPhone and if it is not installed then how to redirect to app store link?

Comment: this can not be possible from app side you have to do coding for this in backend side like server side . otherwise option is that when you create URL at that on click means <a herf= "" > put here your app URL of app store so its open app store and if app install then direct you show option that open app or if not install then you show install app option .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add Following lines to your plist file: (DemoTest is my custom URL schema)

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>DemoTest</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>DemoTest</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

Then try to open DemoTest:// from browser URL it will ask you to open the app is installed.

[image]

HTML Code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function() {
                // Deep link to your app goes here
                document.getElementById("l").src = "DemoTest://";

                setTimeout(function() {
                    // Link to the App Store should go here -- only fires if deep link fails                
                    window.location = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/my.app/id123456789?ls=1&mt=8";
                }, 500);
            };
        </script>
        <iframe id="l" width="1" height="1" style="visibility:hidden"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: this should open the app directly from the mail, right? Or will it always open Safari and then transition to the app?

Comment: it will redirect to safari first, then "DemoTest://" URL checks if app installed or not.

Comment: I know, I've used deep linking before but I didn't come across opening the app from somewhere else than the browser. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: what is element "l" ? an anchor tag ? user needs to click on that element ?